# MySQL: Remove from the count if value changed

Tags: mysql, select, count, locate

This is my query where I am selecting the count for `carton_id` but if this carton gets diverted to its 'assign_id` sometime then I want that to be removed from this count.
I can't use "==" because assign_id is always a comma-seperated string like "24,25" but divert_id will be either of these or "999"

```
SELECT 
    assign_id, COUNT(DISTINCT(carton_id))
FROM
    induction
WHERE
    update_timestamp > '2019-11-21 00:00:00' and update_timestamp < '2019-11-22 00:00:00'
        AND LOCATE(divert_id, assign_id) = 0
        AND sorter_id = 2
        GROUP BY assign_id
ORDER BY assign_id;
```

```
carton | assign_id | divert_id |
abc123 | 24,26     | 999       |
abc123 | 24,26     | 999       |
abc123 | 24,26     | 999       |
abc123 | 24,26     | 24        |
```

So the result should be:

```
24,26 | 0
```

But I get the count to be 1.

Comment: can you add some sample example

Comment: @Ravi you looking for some sample data ? I updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you use LOCATE, it fetches for the substring divert_id in assign id, in this case 24 in 24,26 which results LOCATE(divert_id, assign_id) not equal to zero.  Also check group by both assign_id and divert_id. Hope this helps.

Comment: I think I was not able to explain my question. I understand what LOCATE is doing there but what I want is that if the data is like my sample data then the result should be `0` but what I get is the result to be `3` because LOCATE will return "0" 3 times in the above example.

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead of your COUNT:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT
  CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM induction
    WHERE assign_id = i.assign_id
    AND CONCAT(',', assign_id, ',') LIKE CONCAT('%,', divert_id, ',%')
  ) THEN i.carton_id END
)
```

I use `LIKE` instead of `LOCATE` because `LOCATE` would return false positive if for example `divert_id` is `2` and `assign_id` is `20,21`. 
See a simplified [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9FgLUp3x9VMH1dpRyNGGM4/0).
Try also this:

```
MIN(CONCAT(',', assign_id, ',') NOT LIKE CONCAT('%,', divert_id, ',%')) * COUNT(DISTINCT carton_id)
```

See a simplified [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9FgLUp3x9VMH1dpRyNGGM4/1).

Comment: this makes sense but unfortunately MySQL connection is timing out for me as my data size is 160k rows. might need some optimized solution.. :(